# Overflowing issue of React Sidebar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I have some issues with my react-app. The problem is overflowing of the sidebar. When you check the image below you will see that the sidebar menu does not fit as expected.
It is css style is like this: **col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 bd-sidebar**

Is there any idea?

[Sidebar Overflowing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqJL5.png)

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can't really help if you do not provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I will do my best :)